# tensorflow cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

```py
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found.
```

OS: Windows 10

CUDA version: 10.0

Visual studio: 2017 + 2019

Python version: 3.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

1. Uninstall tensorflow
2. Uninstall CUDA
3. Uninstall visual studio
4. Install visual studio
5. Install CUDA
6. Install Tensorflow